# Android subscription receipt validation logic for payment pending

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I am trying to implement server side receipt validation for android subscriptions and I am having a hard time trying to understand how should receipts with payment state pending should be handled.

For context, from the mobile application after user subscribes to a subscription, the purchase token is sent to my java backend where it is used in a get call to the google developer api to validate the purchase. Here is a response example:

`{ "startTimeMillis": "1701183165504", "expiryTimeMillis": "1701183459563", "autoRenewing": true, "priceCurrencyCode": "RON", "priceAmountMicros": "17990000", "countryCode": "RO", "developerPayload": "", "paymentState": 1, "orderId": "GPA.3345-3453-6629-91075", "purchaseType": 0, "acknowledgementState": 0, "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase" }`

After I get this response, i update the user in the database with an active subscription. However, looking at the google documentation, it seems that the parameter paymentState can have different values, one of them being payment pending.

I don't understand how the payment pending should be handled by the backend and then by the mobile application which expects a boolean response from the server if the purchase was verified or not.

My questions are:

- Should i grant the user the rights associated with an active subscription in this case? If yes, what if the payment never comes through. If no, what if the payment comes through later and he does not get the benefits.
- What do i respond to the mobile application. Do i say that the payment was verified or not? If the payment comes through as verified but then i do not grant the benefits should I create another page in the app where I say that your subscriptions is being processed, come back later. The application only works with an active subscription.